# Why won't Eevee evolve even after renaming it in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I read that there's a trick where you rename your Eevee to *Rainer* and it will evolve into Vaporeon (and likewise, other names will result in other evolutions), but it's not working for me.

- This is the only Eevee I have
- Eevee has a CP value of 188
- I have set its name to *Rainer*
- I restarted the app

What are the possibilities of the things I'm doing wrong? Do I still have to have 25 candies to evolve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes,** you still need to feed your Eevee candies to evolve it. The trick you're referring to is a popular trick to control which Pokémon Eevee will evolve into.

In the traditional games, you need to give Eevee an evolution stone to make it evolve. A Water Stone for Vaporeon, a Thunder Stone for Jolteon, and a Fire Stone for Flareon. Since these stones don't exist in Pokémon Go, Eevee evolves randomly into either.

To avoid having to rely on luck, people have attempted to determine what Eevee will evolve into. Eventually, it was discovered that renaming Eevee allows players to define which Pokémon Eevee will evolve into, assuming that evolution had not been registered in their Pokédex before:

| Evolution | Eevee Nickname | Regular Evolution method |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vaporeon | Rainer | Chosen at random if no other evolution requirement is met |
| Jolteon | Sparky | Chosen at random if no other evolution requirement is met |
| Flareon | Pyro | Chosen at random if no other evolution requirement is met |
| Espeon | Sakura | Walk 10km with Eevee as your Buddy, and evolve in the day |
| Umbreon | Tamao | Walk 10km with Eevee as your Buddy, and evolve at night |
| Leafeon | Linnea | Evolve near Pokéstop under the effect of Mossy Lure |
| Glaceon | Rea | Evolve near Pokéstop under the effect of Glacial Lure |
| Sylveon | Kira | Earn 70 Hearts as your buddy |

Restarting the game is only used to ensure that your Eevee has been renamed, since the servers aren't always available. By restarting, you can determine if your Eevee has been successfully renamed *before* you spend candies to evolve it.

Of course, this doesn't change the fact that you *still* need candies to evolve your Pokémon. Also keep in mind that the trick only works once per nickname (thanks @MBorg).

Comment: "the trick only works if you haven't registered the respective evolution in your Pokédex yet." is not entirely correct. The trick does work if it's registered in the Pokedex, but the trick only works once per nickname. For example, if I have Jolteon registered but haven't used the nickname trick with Sparky, I can still use it with Sparky once.

Answer (score -1):

in the pokedex it says the the environment in which the eevee lives will affect the way it evolves, but changing where you evolve your eevee will not make a difference. After the update many of my friends and I have been getting almost exclusively Jolteons. Maybe because we have a lot of vaporeons. Renaming your Pokemon Rainer over and over again used to result in a lot of vaporeons, but now it only works once. Jolteons are more common because when you evolve them the cp multiplier is lower, so you can evolve 3 CP 650+ eevees and have three 1300 jolteons :( whole if you'd gotten vaporeons the CPs would have been higher.